# Print some elements on a new line in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
a = ["748","994","530","47","178","908","374","188","88","78","56","93","30",
     "197","39","0","160","205","69","98","58","55","50","31","19","13","11",
     "20","20","15","650","175","259","87","193","59","48","47","19","18",
     "30","14","21"]
```

How can I print first 17 elements on a line, after next 17 elements on a new line an so on to the end?  If there is a posibility to create a function, not with:

```
print a[:18]
print[18:36]
....
print [n-17:n+1]
```

After I want to convert them to numbers.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) accepts (optional) `start`, `stop`, (optional) `step` parameters:

Using that you can get starting indexes: 0, 17, 34, ....

With that, use slicing notation, you can get desired sub-lists.

```
>>> a = ["748","994","530","47","178","908","374","188","88","78","56","93", ...]

>>> for i in range(0, len(a), 17):
...     print a[i:i+17]
...
['748', '994', '530', '47', '178', '908', '374', '188', '88', '78', '56', '93', '30', '197', '39', '0', '160']
['205', '69', '98', '58', '55', '50', '31', '19', '13', '11', '20', '20', '15', '650', '175', '259', '87']
['193', '59', '48', '47', '19', '18', '30', '14', '21']

>>> for i in range(0, len(a), 17):
...     print ' '.join(a[i:i+17])
...
748 994 530 47 178 908 374 188 88 78 56 93 30 197 39 0 160
205 69 98 58 55 50 31 19 13 11 20 20 15 650 175 259 87
193 59 48 47 19 18 30 14 21
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
print "\n".join(str(a[i:i+17])[1:-1] for i in range(0,len(a),17))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are beginning to learn python. I would highly recommend looking into "for loops" https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements. Also check out xrange/range, they make is easy to for over numbers. xrange and range use the format range([start,] end, [[skip]]). range() and xrange() both are inclusive for the start, but exclusive for end. The brackets are used to denote optional input. So, only providing 1 input really means range(0,end,1). Providing two inputs means range(start,end,1). Finally providing 3 inputs means range(start,end,skip). Also keep in mind that xrange is only uses in loops because it doesn't actually generate a list, xrange is considered an iterator.

Examples of xrange/range:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(5,10)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(5,10,2)
[5, 7, 9]
```

In order to convert variables into different types, you can cast them. So, int(n) converts whatever n is into an integer. Likewise str(s) will convert whatever s is into a string. Trying to convert a variable into something that it cannot be will throw an exception. For example: int("hellow world!") will not work since "hello world!" doesn't make sense as an integer.

```
# this function will print out n elements per line
# use printNElements(a, 17) to print out 17 at a time
def printNElements(a, n):
    for index in xrange(0,len(a),n):
        print a[index:index+n]

# this converts all the strings in list a to integers
a = [int(n) for n in a]
```